# Batch file and task schedule

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I need to modify a job/task on different computers that I created as a task schedule. I created a batch file to do it (please see below). It uses that administrator account to run the job. The task is modified, but the task doesn't run because I can't set it to run whether the user is logged on or not. How can I set the job to run whether the user is logged on or not? I don't know how to add this code to the batch file. Please help.

```
{SchTasks /Create  /TN MyWeeklyReboot /TR "C:\WINDOWS\RebootMyself.vbs" /ST 13:30 /SD 12/23/2014 /SC Weekly /D TUE  /ru %computername%\Administrator }
```

Answer (score 0):

Scheduled tasks will run regardless of whether or not the user is logged on.
If you add the /it option, the task will only run if the user the task runs under is logged on.
Source: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772785(v=ws.10).aspx/